# warning the user of reverse/over voltage applied to input

Tags: circuit-protection

I have an embedded board that I don't want it not to work due to burned or zapped components.

I want to add a protection circuit to the input power lines of the board to protect it.

What I need is a circuit that blocks two thing and warns the user by turning a 5V buzzer on (The buzzer has only two leads(+5V and GND) with built in oscillator)

(edit:I don't want to lose 1.4 volts because of a diode bridge. The normal power source is just a 3.7 volt Lithium-ion battery. The board converts it to 5 volt using a CN6009 step-up switching voltage converter. And the step-up regulator will only work with more than 3 volts.)

The protector should do the followings:

- reverse voltage
- over-voltage (more than 5.1V)

The blocker part is easy: A 5.1V zener diode

But the problems turn up.

In both cases mentioned:

- The protection circuit will short-circuit the input power supply and it can damage the power supply.
- The power rating of the zener diode may not be sufficient and the zener will heat or blow.

Even if all of those above go well, we have another problem: How to bias the buzzer? The input voltage is variable but the voltage of buzzer is 5V.

Comment: Shematics needed. What the input, power supply voltage and buzzer have in common?

Comment: I want to know how to design the schematic! How can I draw one when I don't know how to?

Comment: A buzer is like a speaker, it needs AC signal, so don't understand about biasing the buzzer and those 5V. "The protection circuit will short-circuit the input power supply and it can damage the power supply" , how is this possible if you don't have a schematics yet? What PSU and how the supply volatge comes in short?

Comment: No! I have a buzzer that works with simple DC 5v. It has a built in oscillator.

Comment: Bridge rectifier on the input then it will work either way round.

Comment: I don't want to lose 1.4 volts because of a diode bridge. The normal power source is just a 3.7 volt Lithium-ion battery. The board converts it to 5 volt using a CN6009 step-up switching voltage converter. And the step-up regulator will only work with more than 3 volts.

Comment: Fuse the input, use your zener diode put the buzzer over the fuse.

Comment: Can you provide a schematic? Will the circuit cover the things above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work if the buzzer requires significantly less current (is higher impedance) to operate than the circuit you are protecting. - but you may want a buzzer that will operate on a lower supply voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6Vk1e.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If reverse connected, the zener conducts, the fuse blows and there will be Vin (less diode drops) across the buzzer. If over voltage the zener conducts, fuse blows and you then have a voltage divider with buzzer and your load. Buzzer will sound if it has lowest current requirement.

I have shown bridge rectifier across fuse to allow for either scenario, alternative would be non polarised buzzer, or 2 buzzers back to back. Another alternative would be to use a relay. Wire relay coil across fuse, use the relay contacts to switch on a buzzer supply circuit with its own dedicated supply circuit.

Comment: Your schematic NEEDS the fuse to blow to make the buzzer buzz. And  are you sure that the buzzer will have 5 volts over it's terminals?

Comment: yes, you can use a resetable fuse https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resettable_fuse.  Or look at current operated relays. No the buzzer would have less than 5V (diode drops, and/or voltage divider) as explained

Comment: PTC? Aren't they a sort of temperature related resistor?

Comment: @BlueSky PTC is more like a slang term for a polyfuse. It doesn't operate based on temperature, per se.

Comment: Yes, but they 'trip' and maintain a significantly higher resistance till the current drops to very low levels when they return to low resistance.

Answer (score 0):

Place a zener diode in series with a relay.  The relay should shut off power to the rest of the device while at the same time activating a buzzer or alarm or tornado siren or whatever else you want.  This won't short the PS nor will it burn the zener.

Comment: You probably mean a solid state relay, since mechanical relay will give enough time for the reverse voltage to do its damage.

Comment: Yes, a SSR, or a fast acting relay (there are a few)